# Do I need these handmade components (React.Fragment that will passthrough props and conditionnal wrapper)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I feel I just reinvented the wheel and it might not be round, because I'm new to the React ecosystem.

I have written these components :

```
const ForwardPropsWrapper = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    return React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, rest))
}
```

**Note that it just forwards its props to its children.**

```
const ConditionalWrapper = ({ condition, children, ...rest }) => {
    return (!condition || condition(rest)) ?
    React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, rest))
    : null;
}
```

**`condition` is a function and it's passed the wrapper's props**

I use it with `react-admin`'s to replace a `ReferenceField` inside a `Datagrid` with two fields combined :

```
<Datagrid rowClick="edit">
    {/*
    `Datagrid` will pass props to `ForwardPropsWrapper`
    */}
    <ForwardPropsWrapper label="User / Role">
        {/*
        Both `ConditionalWrapper`s will receive props passed by `Datagrid`
        through `ForwardPropsWrapper` and call the `condition` function
        with these props as argument
        */}
        <ConditionalWrapper condition={props=>props.record.RoleId}>
            <ReferenceField source="RoleId" reference="role">
                <TextField source="name" />
            </ReferenceField>
        </ConditionalWrapper>
        <ConditionalWrapper condition={props=>props.record.UserId}>
            <ReferenceField source="UserId" reference="user">
                <TextField source="email" />
            </ReferenceField>
        </ConditionalWrapper>
    </ForwardPropsWrapper>
</Datagrid>
```

Why ?

`ForwardPropsWrapper` because `react-admin`'s `Datagrid` expects **one** child per column and passes props to it (the record). A `React.Fragment` is not good enough because it will swallow up the props.

`ConditionalWrapper` is explicit, I need to show either one of the two components depending on the props that `Datagrid` passes them. The condition needs to be evaluated with the props that are passed to the wrapped component by `Datagrid` so I can't use a simple ternary condition in the template.

So... I can't believe this is the way to go.

Is there a way to achieve this without writing custom components ?

What problems may I run into with the components above ?

Criticism is expected please !

Comment: They seem to be overengineered. The problem is overhead. It's not significant but it can accumulate if you're using abstractions everywhere. I'm quite sure there are third-party libs that contain like https://github.com/sindresorhus/react-extras , but usually you don't even need them.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I was right saying this was all useless. Just needed to create a custom Field component.

```
<Datagrid rowClick="edit">
    <TextField source="id" />
    <DualReferenceField label="User / Role" />
    <TextField source="action" />
    <TextField source="subject" />
    <TextField source="criteria" />
    <TextField source="name" />
</Datagrid>
```

```
const DualReferenceField = props => {
    const hasRole = props.record.RoleId;
    const hasUser = props.record.UserId;
    return (
        <>
        { hasRole ? 
        <ReferenceField source="RoleId" reference="role" {...props}>
            <FunctionField render={(record) => {
                return (
                    <span>{record.name} <small>(role)</small></span>
                )
            }} />
        </ReferenceField>
        : null }
        { hasUser ?
        <ReferenceField source="UserId" reference="user" {...props}>
            <TextField source="email" />
        </ReferenceField>
        : null }
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering `<ForwardPropsWrapper label="User / Role">` is intended to produce DRYer code, the problem with it is that it affects only its own children. In case there are nested or other elements that don't have common direct parent, they will stay WET.

Depending on the case could be be written as:

```
const commonProps = { label: 'User / Role' };

...

<Foo {...commonProps} foo={'bar'} />
<Foo {...commonProps} foo={'baz'} />
```

Or as a HOC:

```
const withLabel = (Comp, label) => props => <Comp {...props} label={label}/>

const FooWithUserRoleLabel = withLabel(Foo, 'User / Role');

...

<FooWithUserRoleLabel foo={'bar'} />
<FooWithUserRoleLabel foo={'baz'} />
```

Or just be left WET because common `label="User / Role"` attribute doesn't make the code harder to read or more bulky than other solutions.

As for `ConditionalWrapper`, there is already a ternary and short-circuit evaluation, use them where possible:

```
{ condition && <Foo /> }

{ condition ? (
  <Bar />
) : (
  <Baz />
)}
```

The actual problem here is that the recipe that `Datagrid` uses to provide data to children is inflexible, traversing children and providing them with extra props. This makes cumbersome wrappers necessary in case props need to be processed.

A more flexible and commonly used pattern to achieve the same goal is [*render prop*](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), or, more specifically, its special case, *function as a child*. A wrapper for `Datagrid` could be provided to use instead of original component:

```
const DatagridWrapper = (children, ...props) => {
  const render = React.Children.only(children);
  const Body = props => render(props);

  return <Datagrid {...props}><Body/></Datagrid>;
};
```

All grid data is received in a callback that can process in any way and return elements to render.

```
<DatagridWrapper rowClick="edit">
  {gridData => <>
    {gridData.record.RoleId && (
      <ReferenceField label="User / Role" source="RoleId" reference="role">
        <TextField source="name" />
      </ReferenceField>
      ...
  </>}
</DatagridWrapper>
```

Comment: Will the purpose of `ForwardPropsWrapper` is not to prevent writing the label twice, but to make the two children seem like one to the parent component, like a Fragment would, but passing the props through.
As for ConditionnalWrapper, I need it because the condition is evaluated with props of the component itself, not the parent scope. I'll edit the question to make that all clearer.

Comment: I see. I'd say the problem here is that Datagrid was designed in a way that prevents it from being efficiently used in some cases. The pattern it uses (clone children and provide them with magical extra props) isn't really great, especially in this case. You may end up with a bunch of wrappers that fight against the antipattern, while you could address the problem itself. I updated the answer. You can open an issue with  your case explained and a suggestion to add *render as prop* to library API in comps like Datagrid, this would provide a safe change that benefits everyone.